# QuantGuide website question: Spacious uniform Values 1

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

So the question is :https://www.quantguide.io/questions/spacious-uniform-values-i
You sample 101 uniformly random numbers in the interval $(0,1)$. Find the probability that no two of the values selected are within a distance of $1/1000$ of one another. The answer should be in the fully reduced form $(a/b)^c$. Find $a+b+c$.
My attempt:

Basically, we have to find the distribution of lengths between 2 points. Hence it is given as
$$P(len\ge t)=(1-t)^2$$
Now the total no. of such lengths is 100.

The minimum of the 100 lengths should be greater than $1/1000$. Hence the answer according to me will be $(1-1/1000)^{2\cdot 100}$. Hence $a=999,b=1000,c=200$,
but this is not the answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I haven't proven this, but I don't think your distribution of lengths is independent, so you can't just multiply the probabilities. I did get the same expression that $P(len \geq t) = (1-t)^2.$ You likely have to find the distribution of $n$ uniform random variables, but ordered. Maybe google "spacings between uniform random variables."

Comment: Alternatively, there are $\binom{101}{2}$ possible spacings to check, so the number you are exponentiating by is wrong.

Comment: 1mdlrjcmed I am still not able to get . Could you please post a detailed solution

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2342709?seq=1 I think if you slightly change the argument in here you can get the result, I might do it a bit later if I have some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect.

Randomly take n points from $(0,1)$ line. Suppose the minimum distance between any two points is $t$, then remaining points can just be take in remaining $1-(n-1)t$ because $n$ points generate $n-1$ lines. Then just randomly take the $n$ points.
$P(min len >= t) = (1 - (n-1)t)^n$. So the results should be $120$.

Hint:
compare this problem to the line broken problem: a chalk falls into the ground and break into $n$ pieces randomly. "Randomly" means the lengths of the pieces are randomly generated and sum is the length of the chalk. What is the probability that the minimum piece has a length greater than $k$?